# Automating source code modification with Jenkins CI

Tags: jenkins, scripting, automation, continuous-integration

I know that Jenkins can be made to run scripts, but I am not sure about the extent of what's possible with these scripts.

Assume that I have a bunch of projects in git. I can write a bash script to locally automate the steps like pulling the source code, modifying it, building and deploying it to the test server.

I want to achieve the same with Jenkins. It's possible to clone repositories and build the binaries through Jenkins. Is it also possible to write a Jenkins script to modify the contents of source files before building them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each jobs, you can define pre-build steps and post-build steps.
A step can be a script and all you can do with bash can be done with Jenkins. The limit is your imagination.

A have some advice for you: If you're using a building tool (you should use one) like maven or gradle, use it to describe all your build logic. Use Jenkins only to launch automatically tests, generate reports and maybe deploy to test environment.

Another advice: Used script langage must be understandable by the server or the nodes, this is why I recommend you to use a scripting langage like Groovy ([many samples here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console))

**Update**

Maven/Gradle/... offers you the possibility to make repeatable your build process on any computer, if you use scripts with Jenkins, you break that.

In my case, I have two test environments:

- one is built locally with an embedded tomcat, an in-memory activeMQ and a HSQLDB database to run integrations tests (all computers, including Jenkins server/nodes execute them). Jenkins is configured to launch build process each time a new commit is detected (many per hours)
- the other is built by Jenkins every nights. It use Docker to build and deploy containers, one with tomcat and my web applications, another with RabbitMQ (it replace ActiveMQ) and another one with PostgresQL (it replace HSQLDB).

If I detail your scenario :

- pulling the source code: must be performed by Jenkins to initialize the job
- modifying it: must be performed by maven
- building: must be performed by maven
- deploying to the test server: can be done by Jenkins (script) or maven (plugins)

Comment: Thank you. Regarding your advice, do you mean I should use maven to execute the scripts and then do a maven build using Jenkins?